# Android sensors, detect phone position and relative movement

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, gyroscope

Hi i consider whether and how can I detect firstly position of phone (it can be some initial position - set by some user calibration). And than move relative to this initial position (direction, distance) potentially do some other position. Then detect that the phone return to initial position.

x1 (init pos) ------------ phone moving [m] ------->     x2 (end pos)

```
      <----------- backward movement ----------
```

Answer (score 2):

In theory, yes, absolutely.

Integrating accelerometer data while keeping track of changing orientation using the gyroscope will let you calculate the change in position from your starting point.

However, in practice integrating accelerometer data twice usually gives terrible accuracy. Any minor error, random noise or bias in the measurement will give an error growing quickly over time.

Thus most positioning solutions use external references (such as UWB beacons, GPS satellites, step counting, map fitting etc, in combination with eachother and/or inertial sensors like accelerometers and gyroscopes).